# CSS Font Face not working in Firefox or IE8

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-8, font-face

My `font-face` is not working in Firefox or IE8.

The files are in the correct sport, here is my css code:

```
@font-face {
                font-family: 'SnellRoundhand-Script';
                src: url('snellroundhandscript.eot');
                src: url('snellroundhandscript.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('snellroundhandscript.woff') format('woff'),
                         url('snellroundhandscript.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('snellroundhandscript.svg#snellroundhandscript') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
        }
```

Could the files be broken? or is there something wrong with my CSS?

I also have this code below that code:

```
@font-face {
                font-family: 'Zapfino';
                src: url('Zapfino.eot');
                src: url('Zapfino.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('Zapfino.woff') format('woff'),
                         url('Zapfino.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('Zapfino.svg#Zapfino') format('svg');
                
                         
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
        }
```

You can view my issues here: http://hearingaidneeds.com/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your .eot file is corrupted for IE and I see no logical reason why FF shouldn't work. Try using [this font face creator](http://fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason Firefox doesn't work is that your WOFF files are not valid WOFF files.  It's worth looking at the web console, which will tell you these things.  Mine says, on your site:

```
[00:07:47.442] downloadable font: table 'cmap': failed to parse table (font-family: "SnellRoundhand-Script" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1)
source: http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/snellroundhandscript.woff @ http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
[00:07:47.442] downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "SnellRoundhand-Script" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1)
source: http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/snellroundhandscript.woff @ http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
[00:07:47.613] downloadable font: table 'cmap': failed to parse table (font-family: "SnellRoundhand-Script" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2)
source: http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/snellroundhandscript.ttf @ http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
[00:07:47.613] downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "SnellRoundhand-Script" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2)
source: http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/snellroundhandscript.ttf @ http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
[00:07:47.613] downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "SnellRoundhand-Script" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:4)
source: (end of source list) @ http://hearingaidneeds.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I try and upload it on font-squirrel. So much like djthoms said, your file is corrupted.

> The page at www.fontsquirrel.com says:
>
> The font 'snell_roundhand_script.ttf' is corrupt and cannot be converted.

Comment: Also please make sure you go back to old questions and accept "answers".

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Font2Web](http://www.font2web.com/), this will converts your font and also create css file and a demo HTML file to show you how to use webfonts on your website - using CSS @font-face

Answer (score 0):

The font files can be corrupt, and probably are. This is not uncommon when using illegal copies of fonts. Contact [Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/), the copyright holder, or its resellers in matters of using their fonts like Snell Roundhand and Zapfino.